# Finding matrix for linear transformation that mirrors in the line x=y

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How do I find the matrix for the linear transformation that mirros the planes vectors(points) in the line x=y? I dont even know the first step

Comment: The first step is to figure out what the transformation does to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: ... (and you should draw a picture!)

Comment: Follow Ian's comment to suggest what must happen to $(x,y).$

Comment: (1,0) transforms to (0,1) and (0,1) transforms to (1,0). Do you always start with this step(with these two exact points) in the xy-plane regardless of the line?

Comment: I solved it, thanks for the help

Comment: The reason you start with that is that the images of those two vectors are the columns of the matrix representation in the standard basis.